# The type or namespace name 'dbConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, class

I am new to C# and Visual Studio. I am trying to write a small application where I can Insert/Update/Delete and Select records from MySQL Database.

I do have programing experience in PHP and other languages but it is my first time with a windows application.

I wrote a class that handles the open/close connection to MySQL and also process queries.

The class name is `dbConnetion` and it is located in `Clases\dbConnetion.cs`

On the form that I want to use this class I put on the top

```
using dbConnetion;
```

but for some reason I keep getting an error on the way I am trying to include the class

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'dbConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\User\C# Projects\POS\POS\newDepartment.cs
```

here is a screenshot on what I am running into

[image]

This is a screenshot of the files

[image]

here is my class code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace POS
{
    public class dbConnetion
    {
        //private OdbcConnection conn; 
        private readonly string mServer;
        private readonly string mDatabase;
        private readonly string mUid;
        private readonly string mPassword;
        private readonly string mPort;
        private readonly string conn_string;
        public dbConnetion()
        {
            mServer = "localhost";
            mDatabase = "pos";
            mUid = "root";
            mPassword = "";
            mPort = "3306";

            conn_string = String.Format("server={0};user={1};database={2};port={3}password={4};", mServer, mUid, mDatabase, mPort, mPassword);



        }

        //Start connection to database
        private bool startConnection(MySqlConnection mConnection)
        {

            try
            {
                mConnection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                return false;
            }

        }


        //Close connection
        private bool closeConnection(MySqlConnection mConnection)
        {
            try
            {
                mConnection.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        public MySqlDataReader getDataSet(string query)
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conn_string);

            if (startConnection(conn) == true)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
                MySqlDataReader dataset = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                closeConnection(conn);

            }
            return dataset;
        }


        public void processQuery(string strSQL, List<MySqlParameter> pars)
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conn_string);


            if (startConnection(conn) == true)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strSQL, conn);

                foreach (MySqlParameter param in pars)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                }

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                closeConnection(conn);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I correct this issue? and how do I include the class correctly?

Comment: You don't need that using. The class and the form are in the same namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple problems here:

- You're trying to use a `using` directive for a *class*. You can't do that (before C# 6, anyway) - you either specify an alias for a class (which you don't want here) or you just specify a *namespace* in order to import all the types in that namespace. (So that you can refer to them by their simple names.)
- Your class is called `dbConnetion` for some reason, but you've got `using dbConnection;`
- Your class is in the `POS` namespace, but you're trying to use it without specifying a namespace
- It looks like your class isn't in a project - it's a solution item. It's probably not being compiled at all. Classes should always be in projects.

Fundamentally, you don't need a `using` directive for it *at all* as you're trying to use it from code in the same namespace. It does need to be in a project though - either the same one as you're trying to use it from, or a referenced projects.

You should also read up on [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) - none of your names follow them at the moment.

Also, it's a bad idea to keep a connection around for any length of time - you should open it, use it, close it. Use a `using` statement to make sure you close it at the end, even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: about your last comments about open/close connection... Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong in my code regarding that? I start connection using startConnection then running command (ie. select....) and then I am closing connection using closeConnection. Pleae help mw understand the issue so I can correct it

Comment: @Mike: You're using an instance variable for it. So if you have two different threads using the same instance of your class, they'll trample over each other. There's no need to keep the instance around at all - just create a completely new instance each time you need to use the database.

Comment: @Jonkeet are you referring to `mConnection = new MySqlConnection(conn_string);` line? should this line be part of the getDataSet method, correct? I just want to make sure I understand you correctly.  thanks you

Comment: @Mike: yes, exactly. Given that everything else is effectively a constant, it's not clear why you need any instances at all...

Comment: I just updated my question with the updated code. can you please tell me if this is what I should be doing? thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: @Mike: Stack Overflow isn't designed for questions which keep changing over time. If you've got code which works now but you're not sure whether it's ideal, you should post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Your class name and the name of class you in using statement are not compatible

```
dbConnetion
dbConnection
```

also if you are in the **same namespace** **it's not need** to import it with **using**

Answer (score 0):

You use `using` with a namespace, not a class. If the consuming class wasn't already in the same namespace, you would swap:

```
using dbConnection;
```

for

```
using POS;
```

But in you case, just remove the line altogether, and instead move the class file to be part of the project, rather than just in a folder in the solution